# Cordova Change AndroidManifest using Config.xml file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am in need to add some tags to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file which is found under

```
platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml
```

As I have read the `AndroidManifest.xml` file gets generated on the fly and it is not advisable to edit it.

So is there a plugin that I can use that will modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for me with the values that I give it in the `config.xml` file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since the [recent release of cordova@6.4.0](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/10/25/tools-release.html) you can use the [`<edit-config>` tag](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) in config.xml to do this without requiring a 3rd party plugin. For example:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/uses-sdk" mode="merge">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Though this is a good answer, and probably the best way to do it for 99% of circumstances I'd like to add a caveat. We use https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme , it adds an intent to the AndroidManifest.xml. Using
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity" mode="merge">
   <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" />
</edit-config>
Results in the intent being removed - you might need to find a different strategy

Comment: @KeithPaulBarrow In order to modify the attribute on `<activity>`, you can alternatively use [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config): `<custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:configChanges" value="keyboardHidden" />`. This will not override changes made by other plugins.

Comment: @DaveAlden - thanks, this is what we did. It's a pity we needed to do this, as it's always good to drop a dependency, but needs must.

Comment: for me I had to use <config-file> tag: <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">

Answer (score 5):

in my case, nothing was working but this one i came up with:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest">
            <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" />
        </edit-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config

By using this plugin you can modify all the platform specific things (iOS and Android) and you get a clean cordova envirement.